# React pass API data to chart

Tags: reactjs, axios

#### Background

- I have an chart which displays static data just fine.

  Using this template https://github.com/creativetimofficial/black-dashboard-react/blob/master/src/variables/charts.js
- On my main page [dash.js] I have an API call, (which I tested presents the data I expect by using `console.log()`.

  I will be looking to have this data working dynamically so I have created it using `useEffect` and `useState`.

For reference;

```js
  const [chrtState, setChrtState] = useState({
    loading: false,
    chartos: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setChrtState({loading: true});
    const apiUrl = `http://example.com/api/request/`;
    axios
      .get(apiUrl, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then(res => {
        setChrtState({loading: false, repos: res.data.characters});
      });
  }, [setChrtState]);

  const setCanvas = name => {
    const apiUrl = `http://example.com/api/request/`;

    axios
      .get(apiUrl, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then(res => {
        setChrtState({loading: false, chartos: res.data.characters});
        //console.log(res.data.characters);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Line
      data={chartExample1[bigChartData + bigChartTime]}
      options={chartExample1.options}
      apiprops={chrtState.chartos}
    />
  );
```

Note: the `data` parameter is used to select a specific chart-type (e.g. data1, data2, etc), this part works fine and isn't related to the APIdata as such.

#### My Problem

I am struggling to work out how to pass the API data to the chart.js

I tried using some other examples of how to pass props but it is proving very confusing for me given that it is already passing `data1: (canvas)` etc.

#### What I've tried

- I tried to add an additional parameter before `data1` (line 77) in charts.js, as follows;

```js
  apiprops: (props) => {
    const {repos} = props;
    console.log(repos);
  },
```

but nothing was printed to the console for this.

- I tried adding the data to `canvas` but this is already passing information used to render the height, width and style of the of the chart.
- I have tried to add the API to the charts.js file, however when I add `import axios from 'axios';` to the top of this page it throws out a syntax error. But I think it makes more sense to pull the API elsewhere and pass as a prop anyway. (please let me know if you disagree).

I am very much still building my knowledge of reactjs so thank you for any help and guidance on this!

#### End goal

For reference, my end goal will be to pass the API data to the chart and then process each dictionary into the `labels` and the `datasets.data` - the API passes in this order

```json
{
 "characters": [
    {
      "label": 123,
      "data": 321
    },
    {
      "label": 456,
      "data": 654
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: useState is for managing variables not creating them

Try separating the data gathering from the charting using a custom hook -- reference: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data 

then you'll be able to do something like this:
```
const [loading, error, data] = useCallMyAPI(with, whatever, params);
if (error) { return <>{error}</>; }  
if (loading) { return <>Loading..</>; }  
const massagedData = massageAPIReturn(data);
// pass the data to chartjs here
```

how wonderful, I can't paste code here...

Comment: Thanks @Joslin, I certainly did miss out my `useEffect` which is making more sense to me know since your comment. I have added this to my code above, however still at a loss when it comes to passing the data over to the chart without completely reworking the code.

Comment: What part of the template are you trying to modify? What component does that code belong to?

Comment: Can you show us the component that renders chart and also where and how that component is being used

Comment: Hi, for clarity - the component that renders the chart is in `chart.js`, (linked at the top of the page (starts on line 76). This is the part I am trying to modify in order that I can pass my data to it as props.
It is used on the dash.js and is shown at the end of my first block of code - namely  `<Line
      data={chartExample1[bigChartData + bigChartTime]}
      options={chartExample1.options}
      apiprops={chrtState.chartos}
    />`
Hope this helps clarify what I'm trying to do - thanks for the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you are trying to inject your API values into the existing functions in charts.js. First, you need to separate the API values into two arrays: labels and data. You can do that with `reduce`

```
  const values = res.data.characters.reduce(
    (acc, character) => ({
      labels: [...acc.labels, character.label],
      data: [...acc.data, character.data],
    }),
    { labels: [], data: [] }
  );
  setChrtState({ loading: false, repos: values });
```

To inject them into the functions, you'll need to modify the functions a little using [currying](https://medium.com/@harouny/currying-in-javascript-arrow-function-sequence-2a510441215a)

```
data1: ({labels, data}) => (canvas) => {
  ...

  return {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        ...
        data,
      },
    ],
  };
},
```

and finally, call the function when passing the data prop to the `Line` component

```
<Line
  data={chartExample1[bigChartData + bigChartTime](chrtState.repos)}
```

Although looking at those functions they seem to have the same code, is just the data is changing, you could use a single function.

**UPDATE**

this would be the complete version of the component

```
  const [chrtState, setChrtState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    repos: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setChrtState({ loading: true });
    const apiUrl = `http://example.com/api/request/`;
    axios
      .get(apiUrl, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const values = res.data.characters.reduce(
          (acc, character) => ({
            labels: [...acc.labels, character.label],
            data: [...acc.data, character.data],
          }),
          { labels: [], data: [] }
        );
        setChrtState({ loading: false, repos: values });
      });
  }, [setChrtState]);

  if (chrtState.loading) {
    return <span>Loading</span>;
  }

  return (
    <Line
      data={chartExample1[bigChartData + bigChartTime](chrtState.repos)}
      options={chartExample1.options}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Thanks @diedu This looks like what I need to get this working. Sorry for my ignorance, but could you please explain where the first segment of code should go? I have inserted it into my axios.get section but I then receive the following error.

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'labels' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`

I also tried adding it to the `setCanvas` axios.get instead of the useEffect and I get this alternative but similar error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'labels' of 'object null' as it is null.`

Comment: furthermore, if I only use the first segment in the axios.get (that is I removed the other to parts calling `(values)` - I receive the following error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined ... still really stuck troubleshooting this - thanks

Comment: @Simon, I added a complete version of the code for the component. You were not handling the loading state; that's possibly why the null values, `setCanvas` is not necessary.

Comment: @Simon can you add the response you are receiving from the API call?

Comment: sorry @diedu, false alarm - I hadn't put the `(chrtState.repos)` part back in the call.
Tested again and it is all working now - thank you so much for your help on this!!!